# ASP.NET Identity user is logged out after 30 minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm developing an app, but I am logged out after 30 minutes, even when I've been active during the last 30 minutes.

This is in the ConfigureAuth method:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, string>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
        getUserIdCallback:(id) => id.GetUserId())
    }
}
```

I am testing the app in IIS Express on localhost.

Comment: does it has something to do with Session Time out. i think default time out is 20 mins, due to which you are logged out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `SlidingExpiration = true` to the list of properties you're setting.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, string>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
        getUserIdCallback:(id) => id.GetUserId())
    },
    // Add this
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    //Use this to customize the timeout duration if the default is too short/long
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) 
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this two line ` regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
        getUserIdCallback:(id) => id.GetUserId())`